# How to set and query multicast address for NDIS Virtual miniport driver?

Tags: windows, filter, wdk, ndis, miniport

I want to add multicast support on virtual Miniport driver . I have a filter driver binds over each physical NIC . As per Microsoft document
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569073(v=vs.85).aspx

I stared to add support multicast address :

**These are my steps :**
In miniport driver : 
during `miniport initialization` i added `MaxMulticastListSize = 32` in  `NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_GENERAL_ATTRIBUTES` .

```
NDIS_MINIPORT_ADAPTER_GENERAL_ATTRIBUTES MiniportAdapterGeneralAttributes;
MiniportAdapterGeneralAttributes.MediaType = NdisMedium802_3;
MiniportAdapterGeneralAttributes.PhysicalMediumType = NdisPhysicalMediumUnspecified;
MiniportAdapterGeneralAttributes.MaxMulticastListSize = 32;
```

also i updated 32 max address in  OID_802_3_MAXIMUM_LIST_SIZE OID .
Next i updated `PacketFilters` in

```
MiniportAdapterGeneralAttributes.SupportedPacketFilters =    NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_DIRECTED |
        NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_MULTICAST |
        NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_BROADCAST |
        NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS |
        NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_MULTICAST;
```

During `OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER` OID set request , i updated the PacketFilters with `DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBuffer` value .

and During `OID_GEN_MAC_OPTION` i am adding macros :  `NDIS_MAC_OPTION_NO_LOOPBACK | NDIS_MAC_OPTION_FULL_DUPLEX | NDIS_MAC_OPTION_8021P_PRIORITY ;`

Next in OID_802_3_MULTICAST_LIST OID set request , i maintained a multicast list

```
OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = 6;
OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesRead = OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength;

do
{

  //check multicast address invalid
  if(OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength % 6){
   OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesRead = 0;
   status = NDIS_STATUS_INVALID_LENGTH;
   break;
   }

   //check multicast address list full
  if(OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength > (VELAN_MAX_MCAST_LIST * 6)){
  status = NDIS_STATUS_MULTICAST_FULL;
  OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = VELAN_MAX_MCAST_LIST * 6;
  break;
  }

 //setting new multicast address list
 NdisZeroMemory(m_ulMcList,VELAN_MAX_MCAST_LIST * MUX_MAC_ADDRESS);
 NdisMoveMemory(m_ulMcList,OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBuffer,OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength);
 m_ulMclistSize = OidRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength / 6;
 status = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;

}while(FALSE);
```

I tested with NDISTester . It has a protocol driver that will bound to the miniport adapter .  But i didn't get any multicast packet during the receive time . Any thing am missing ? I am getting error like `received less than expected percentage of sent` . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide a handler for `OID_802_3_MAXIMUM_LIST_SIZE` .

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.